# Starting new Activity using Intent. NPE at android.content.ContextWrapper.getPackageName

Tags: java, android, android-intent, nullpointerexception

I'm trying to start a new `Activity` using an `Intent`. I've done this successfully in a different app, but that approach doesn't seem to work in this case?

This is my code...

```
 public void startLevelEnd(Context context){
     Intent myIntent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, LevelEndPanel.class);
     FirstActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
 }
```

From my `AndroidManifest.xml` file...

```
<activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name=".LevelEndPanel"></activity>
```

And I call the `startLevelEnd()` routine (fromout a different class) using...

```
FirstActivity.startLevelEnd(this);
```

I get a `NullPointerException` error on the line "Intent myIntent..." (from code snippet above) :

```
04-16 09:46:39.361: E/AndroidRuntime(475):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.getPackageName(ContextWrapper.java:120)
```

Full Log :

```
04-16 14:32:32.870: E/AndroidRuntime(336): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-16 14:32:32.870: E/AndroidRuntime(336): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-16 14:32:32.870: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.getPackageName(ContextWrapper.java:120)
04-16 14:32:32.870: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at android.content.ComponentName.<init>(ComponentName.java:75)
04-16 14:32:32.870: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at android.content.Intent.<init>(Intent.java:2702)
04-16 14:32:32.870: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at happyworx.nl.App.FirstActivity.startLevelEnd(FirstActivity.java:32)
04-16 14:32:32.870: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at happyworx.nl.App.model.components.GameManager.LevelEnd(GameManager.java:89)
04-16 14:32:32.870: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at happyworx.nl.App.model.components.GameManager$1.run(GameManager.java:60)
04-16 14:32:32.870: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
04-16 14:32:32.870: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-16 14:32:32.870: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-16 14:32:32.870: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
04-16 14:32:32.870: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-16 14:32:32.870: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-16 14:32:32.870: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
04-16 14:32:32.870: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
04-16 14:32:32.870: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

For @Sergi, the full class containing the method :

```
package happyworx.nl.Appelz.model.components;


import happyworx.nl.Appelz.AppelzActivity;
import happyworx.nl.Appelz.LevelEndPanel;
import happyworx.nl.Appelz.MainGamePanel;
import happyworx.nl.Appelz.MainThread;
import happyworx.nl.Appelz.R;
import happyworx.nl.Appelz.model.apple;
import happyworx.nl.Appelz.model.glyphs;


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;


public class GameManager extends Activity {

    //Declare Vars
    private static final String TAG = "GameManager";
    public static MainGamePanel panel;
    private static glyphs glyphsCount;
    public static GameManager GameManager = new GameManager();

    public static AppelzActivity AppelzActivity = new AppelzActivity();

    private static Canvas canvas;
    final static int delayMillis = 1000;
    public static boolean count = false;
    public static int i = 6;
    public final static Handler handler = new Handler();


    public final static Runnable runnable = new Runnable()  {

        @Override
        public void run()
        {

            if (SlotManager.alSlottedFruitList.size() > 0){
            //TODO Create Full screen countdown timer
                Log.d("", "Countdown Timer in GameManager " + i);

                i--;
                if (count && i > -1) // stop timer when count is false
                {
                    handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000);
                } else {
                    if (i == -1){
                        Log.d("", "RoundUp the Level");

                        GameManager.LevelEnd();
                    }
                    // reset Countdown (if basket outside checkout)
                    i = 6;
                }
            } else {
                // reset Countdown (if slot has no fruits)
                i = 6;
            }
        }
    };


    public void LevelEnd(){
        // First, count the Fruits in the slot
        SlotManager.countSlotInv();
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();


        // Fill itemIds with the types of fruits
        for (apple a : SlotManager.alSlottedFruitList){
            Integer itemId = Integer.valueOf(a.FruitType);
            list.add(itemId);

            Set<Integer> unique = new HashSet<Integer>(list);
        }
            for (int key = 0; key < 3 ; key++) {
                System.out.println(key + " : " + Collections.frequency(list, key));     
            }
            startLevelEnd();
    }

    public void startLevelEnd(){
         Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, LevelEndPanel.class);
         this.startActivity(myIntent);
     }

    public GameManager() 
    {
    }
```

The LevelEndPanel class :

```
package happyworx.nl.Appelz;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;



public class LevelEndPanel extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

 private static final String TAG = LevelEndPanel.class.getSimpleName();
 private Button btnNewMission;

 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.level);

        btnNewMission = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNewMission);
        btnNewMission.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AppelzActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }});


 }


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

}
```

And the MainThread :

```
package happyworx.nl.Appelz;

import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;

public class MainThread extends Thread {

 private static final String TAG = MainThread.class.getSimpleName();

 private SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
 private MainGamePanel gamePanel;
 public static boolean running;
 public static Canvas canvas;

 public void setRunning(boolean running) {
 MainThread.running = running;
 }

 public MainThread(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, MainGamePanel gamePanel) {
  super();
  this.surfaceHolder = surfaceHolder;
  this.gamePanel = gamePanel;

 }

 @Override
 public void run() {
     // Canvas canvas;
      Log.d(TAG, "Starting game loop");
      while (running) {
      MainThread.canvas = null;
       // try locking the canvas for exclusive pixel editing on the surface
       try {
           MainThread.canvas = this.surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
        synchronized (surfaceHolder) {
         // update game state
         this.gamePanel.update();
         // render state to the screen
         // draws the canvas on the panel
         this.gamePanel.onDraw(MainThread.canvas);
        }
       } finally {
        // in case of an exception the surface is not left in
        // an inconsistent state
        if (MainThread.canvas != null) {
         surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(MainThread.canvas);
        }
       } // end finally
      }
     }
}
```

And the basket class, which starts the CountDown timer in GameManager (maybe here is my error?!?)

```
package happyworx.nl.Appelz.model;

import happyworx.nl.Appelz.MainGamePanel;
import happyworx.nl.Appelz.model.components.GameManager;
import happyworx.nl.Appelz.model.components.SlotManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;

public class basket {

 private Bitmap bitmap; // the actual bitmap
 private int x;   // the X coordinate
 private int y;   // the Y coordinate'
 public static int width;
 public static int height;
 public float X = 100;
 public float Y = 100;

 private boolean touched; // if droid is touched/picked up

 public basket(Bitmap bitmap, int x, int y) {
  this.bitmap = bitmap;

  width = bitmap.getWidth(); 
  height = bitmap.getHeight(); 
 }

 public Bitmap getBitmap() {
  return bitmap;
 }
 public void setBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
  this.bitmap = bitmap;
 }

 public int getWidth(){
      return bitmap.getWidth();
     }

     public int getHeight(){
      return bitmap.getHeight();
     }

 public int getX() {
  return x;
 }



 public void setX(float x) {

    // if basket is further than slotmargin 
     if (x + width/2 > SlotManager.SlotmarginX) {
        // if basket is NOT in CheckOut area    
         if (this.Y < MainGamePanel.height - 80 - height/2){
            x = SlotManager.SlotmarginX - width/2;

        } else {
            // if basket IS in CheckOut area
            x = MainGamePanel.width - width/2;

            // Start the countdown timer if not already running
            if (!GameManager.count){
                GameManager.count=true;
                GameManager.handler.postDelayed(GameManager.runnable, 0);                               
            }

        }
    } else {

        // Basket is NOT in CheckOut area; stop countdown timer
        GameManager.count=false;
    }

     this.X = x;
 }


 public int getY() {
  return y;
 }
 public void setY(int y) {
        if (y + height/2 > MainGamePanel.height - 80){
            y = MainGamePanel.height - 80 - height/2;
        }


  this.Y = y;
 }


 public boolean isTouched() {
  return touched;
 }

 public void setTouched(boolean touched) {
  this.touched = touched;
 }

 public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
      canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, X - width/2, Y - height/2, null);
 }

 public void handleActionDown(int eventX, int eventY) {
  if (eventX >= (X - width/ 2) && (eventX <= (X + width/2))) {
   if (eventY >= (Y - height/ 2) && (eventY <= (Y + height/ 2))) {
    // basket touched
    setTouched(true);
   } else {
    setTouched(false);
   }
  } else {
   setTouched(false);
  }

 }
}
```

Comment: add full logcat here and also put line its not intent myintent...

Comment: Not constructive.. I've added a full LC, what value does it add? The line is in the code snippet above.

Comment: you are asking a question because you don't have the answer to it. you can leave the estimation of the added value of logcat to the people who answer. For example, it can tell us that you haven't posted the code that actually crashes. (in `happyworx.nl.App.FirstActivity.startLevelEnd(FirstActivity.java:32)`). The code you posted is inconsistent with the starttrace as in this code, the startLevelEnd is apparently a method of GameManager rather than of FirstActivity.

Answer (score 7):

My bet here is that you are trying to start an activity from an activity that is not fully initialized.

Make sure FirstActivity.onCreate has been called before starting another activity.

Comment: I tried FirstActivity fa = new FirstActivity(); fa.startLevelEnd(this); - This would test your theory, right? Unfortunately, it didn't solve the issue. Also, in FirstActivity, the view is created with the canvas and such.. so I know it already ran, because LevelEnd can only be triggered by the user using that Canvas? Please elaborate if I mis-interpreted your suggestion.

Comment: the Context for an activity is not initialized during the constructor, but much later. calling `FirstActivity fa = new FirstActivity(); fa.startLevelEnd(this);` will _always_ fail.

Comment: Do you have a suggestion on how to accomplish this, njzk2? -- I also tried to do the startActivity right from the running Activity, but that didn't solve my NPE.. :(

Comment: make sure you use the currently running activity as a context for creating the intent and starting the activity

Comment: Is there any way to check (for instance with a Log.d what activity I'm actually using for creating the intent and if it is running??)

Comment: it should be pretty obvious. are you calling startActivity from a started activity ?

Comment: I'm having the same problem, and it's after I call `popBackStackImmediate` to remove the current fragment.

Answer (score 5):

The error looks like the context provided to the Intent constructor is null.

The code should look more like:

```
public void startLevelEnd(Context context){
     Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, LevelEndPanel.class);
     context.startActivity(myIntent);
 }
```

Be sure that you call `startLevelEnd` from an activity using this call

```
startLevelEnd(this)
```

If `startLevelEnd` is located in the same Activity class that is calling it, simplify it:

```
public void startLevelEnd(){
     Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, LevelEndPanel.class);
     startActivity(myIntent);
 }
```

Comment: trying your solution now... Nope.. sorry, can't get it to function properly. I must be missing something.. but what!?

Answer (score 1):

I'm fairly sure that you have to use a context for the first parameter in an Intent, and since you have a context as a parameter on your startLevelEnd method, you can try

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent (context, LevelEndPanel.class);
context.startActivity(myIntent);
```

I think you're getting the NullPointerException because your class can't see the FirstActivity. But it depends on where the startLevelEnd method is. And since you don't say where it is, try it!

Comment: StartLevelEnd routine is in FirstActivity. Yes, the first is a Context and I deliberatly tried your solution first (to pass the context).. When that didn't work, I resorted to changing 'context' to FirstActivity.this .. same error. So, in terms of your answer; I'm afraid it's not the right answer to this problem.