# Intent and StartActivity to go to Market from a Dialog button

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent, nullpointerexception

I really can't get my head around Activity, Intent and start.. even after reading Lars Vogels Tutorial ([Tutorial on Intents](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidIntent/article.html))

I've tried to make the question as clean and simple as possible.

2 classes (KKOTestActivity, VersionChangeInfo) and one AndroidManifest.

Goal : Class KKOTestActivity starts, fires off VersionChangeInfo. That class shows a dialog with three buttons. One of them is the go-to-market. That's where the problem is. When the user presses that button, I get NPE Error (see error log below). I really don't understand what I'm doing here, so a link to Intents-for-dummies or something would also be highly appreciated :). Thanks!

KKOTestActivity :

```
package happyworx.nl.KKOTest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;


public class KKOTestActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        new VersionChangeInfo(this).show();
    }
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
    }
}
```

VersionChangeInfo.java :

```
package happyworx.nl.KKOTest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.pm.PackageInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;


public class VersionChangeInfo extends Activity {

    private String VCI_PREFIX = "vci_";
    private Activity mActivity;

    public VersionChangeInfo(final Activity context) {
        mActivity = context;
    }

    private PackageInfo getPackageInfo() {
        PackageInfo pi = null;
        try {
             pi = mActivity.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(mActivity.getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return pi;
    }

     public void show() {
        PackageInfo versionInfo = getPackageInfo();

        // the eulaKey changes every time you increment the version number in the AndroidManifest.xml
        final String eulaKey = VCI_PREFIX + versionInfo.versionCode;
        final SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mActivity);
        boolean hasBeenShown = prefs.getBoolean(eulaKey, false);
        if(hasBeenShown == false){

            // Show the Eula
            String title = mActivity.getString(R.string.app_name) + " v" + versionInfo.versionName;

            //Includes the updates as well so users know what changed.
            String message = mActivity.getString(R.string.updates) + "\n\n" + mActivity.getString(R.string.eula);

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mActivity)
                    .setTitle(title)
                    .setMessage(message)
                    .setPositiveButton("Ga naar Market", new Dialog.OnClickListener() {

                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {                           
                            // Mark this version as read.
                            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
                         //   editor.putBoolean(eulaKey, true);
                         //   editor.commit();
                            dialogInterface.dismiss();

                            final Intent MyIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
                            Uri.parse("market://details?id=happyworx.nl.Flashwords"));
                            startActivity(MyIntent);
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("Later", new Dialog.OnClickListener() {

                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                            dialogInterface.dismiss();
                        }



                    })

                    .setNeutralButton("Niet meer tonen", new Dialog.OnClickListener(){
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
                            editor.putBoolean(eulaKey, true);
                            editor.commit();
                            dialogInterface.dismiss();
                        }
                    })
                    ;
            builder.create().show();
        }
    }

}
```

AndroidManifest.xls

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="happyworx.nl.KKOTest"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".KKOTestActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

                <activity
            android:name=".VersionChangeInfo"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Error Log :

```
04-19 08:06:45.711: E/AndroidRuntime(15186): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-19 08:06:45.711: E/AndroidRuntime(15186): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-19 08:06:45.711: E/AndroidRuntime(15186):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2827)
04-19 08:06:45.711: E/AndroidRuntime(15186):    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:2933)
04-19 08:06:45.711: E/AndroidRuntime(15186):    at happyworx.nl.KKOTest.VersionChangeInfo$1.onClick(VersionChangeInfo.java:63)
04-19 08:06:45.711: E/AndroidRuntime(15186):    at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:159)
04-19 08:06:45.711: E/AndroidRuntime(15186):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-19 08:06:45.711: E/AndroidRuntime(15186):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-19 08:06:45.711: E/AndroidRuntime(15186):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
04-19 08:06:45.711: E/AndroidRuntime(15186):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-19 08:06:45.711: E/AndroidRuntime(15186):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-19 08:06:45.711: E/AndroidRuntime(15186):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
04-19 08:06:45.711: E/AndroidRuntime(15186):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
04-19 08:06:45.711: E/AndroidRuntime(15186):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you're missing a `<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />` in your AndroidManifest.xml, inside the `<intent-filter>`.

But when this'll be done, it'll crash anyways, because the Market is not installed on the emulator. It should work fine on a device though.

Comment: YES! It works now. As far as I can see, this is the complete answer to my question. Thank you very much. If you have the time, I would like you to look at one of my other Intent-problems : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10172039/starting-new-activity-using-intent-npe-at-android-content-contextwrapper-getpac/10204964#10204964 thanks!

Comment: Not quite; by adding the `<action>`-tag to your manifest you're declaring that your application can handle the `Intent.VIEW` - which is not the case, unless you want your application itself to handle the `market://`-link (and not refer to Market). In this case, adding the <action> is unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

You're not doing it wrong; the reason you're getting the `ActivityNotFoundException` is because there are no applications installed on your device that can handle the `Intent.ACTION_VIEW`. The reason for this is that you chose to view a `market://`-URI rather than `http(s)://`. You're probably working on the emulator, which doesn't contain the Market.

You have three options:

1. Install the Market on your emulator (wouldn't know how).
2. Just keep it like it is; it'll work on devices with the Market installed. Wrap your call to `startActivity()` in a `try { .. } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) { ... }`.
3. Change your URI to `http://` or `https://`.

The third option will work in the emulator, even without the Market installed. On your device, it will prompt whether you'd like to open the URI in the Market or in the Browser.

I'll try and explain:

```
// First, you're basically telling Android you want some Activity
// that is not your current Activity to handle an action:
// you wan't `some application` to view `something`.
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

// Next, you're making it clear you want an application to view a specific URI.
// In this case, you're asking for something that can handle a "market://"-URI.
i.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=happyworx.nl.Flashwords"));

// Finally, you're asking Android to actually broadcast the Intent.
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: YES!! Thank you for your clear Explanation on the ActivityNotFound error. I get this now! +1 :)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=happyworx.nl.KKOTest"));
startActivity(intent);
```

and check your package name. In your class you use **happyworx.nl.Flashwords** in manifest **happyworx.nl.KKOTest**, this packages names must be equals if you built link to your application. Also you can use getPackageName() method instead of "your.package.name"